# Is there a closed form for the values $x$ where $f(x) = 0$ and when $f(x) = 1$

Tags: transcendental-equations

I posted an answer to the question [An Integral Involving The Inverse Of $f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533530/an-integral-involving-the-inverse-of-fx-log-x-log-cos-xx-tan-x) and my answer depends on knowing where the function $f(x)$ is $0$ or $1$. The function itself is

$$f(x) = \log x - \log \cos x + x \tan x$$

on $x \in (0,\pi/2)$. On this range it can clearly be written as

$$f(x) = \log\left(\frac{x}{\cos x}\right)+ x \tan x$$

Is there a closed for $x_0$ and $x_1$ where $f(x_0) = 0$ and $f(x_1)=1$? Numerically these two values are

$$x_0 = 0.576412723\ldots$$
$$x_1 = 0.807626251\ldots$$

I would accept an interesting series form for either one as "closed enough".

Comment: It seems that $x_0=\Re( \mathrm{LambertW(i)}).\;$ With this value $f(x_0)=0$ is confirmed upto 1000 digits with Maple.

Comment: I just checked with Mathematica. It seems that it should be $x_0=\Im( \mathrm{LambertW(i)}).\;$ or $x_0= \mathrm{LambertW(1)}
.\;$

Comment: Never mind on that latter part of my comment.

Comment: Yes, sorry, a very misleading typo. Of course it is $\Im(\mathrm{LambertW}(i))$. But I can give no further inside right now. The value was found be googling for 0.576412723  and some experiments.

Comment: It's interesting to see this because I've just been messing around with the function and managed to "simplify" the equation $f(x) = 0$ to

$$ x \tan x = \mathrm{LambertW}(\sin x)$$

Thanks for your insight thought @gammatester

Comment: @gammatester How would one solve for $x=\Im(W(i))$? Maybe it is because of the [branches of Lambert W](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Elementary_properties,_branches_and_range) relates to $\frac{\tan(x)}x$